# Run the current command and pipe the output to fzf

Tags: fish

What would be an easy way to bind a key binding from fish to run the current command prompt and pipe it to fzf for easy search/selection?

i.e. a 1 key-press way of accomplishing `| fzf (enter)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a pretty straightforward `bind` function, if I'm understanding correctly.  At its simplest:

Saved in `~/.config/fish/functions/__append_pipe_fzf.fish`:

```
function __append_pipe_fzf
    set -l cmd (commandline -b)
    commandline -r $cmd" | fzf"
    commandline -f execute
end
```

And then bind it to a key with something like:
`bind -k nul __append_pipe_fzf`
nul binds to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> on Mac, which I believe is your case).

Of course, you can make this more robust by checking to see if the current command ends with a process starting with `| fzf` and remove it if so.  Right now, it could conceivably append the `| fzf` even when you already have one there.  Also, if you pressed it when the current commandline ended in `|`, I think it would generate an "or" statement, instead of what you want.

Comment: Thanks! Minor note, I think the first commandline probably doesn't want the `-o` since multi-word commands will be split into multiple lines each appended with a `| fzf`.

Comment: Thanks!  You're absolutely right.  I'd offer to have you update the answer if it weren't for Stack's "6 character minimum" rule.  So at least I can give you some upvote rep on the assist in the comment.